# Why can I still use WiFi with a disconnected Wi-Fi adapter?

Tags: wireless-networking, laptop-repair

I was about to post a question about why is my Wi-Fi connection being slow since I disassembled and reassembled my laptop but I've just figure out that I forgot to reconnect the Wi-Fi adapter. Now My question is: how on earth could my computer wirelessly connect to my smartphone portable hotspot without a Wi-Fi adapter ? I don't know as much as I would like about computers... Is the Wi-Fi adapter to a laptop what is the turbo to a car engine ?

Comment: What *exactly* did you forget to reconnect? Your Wi-Fi cards antenna connectors?

Comment: The likely answer is that you were using Bluetooth with your 'phone as a hot-spot.

Answer (score 5):

Its likely you simply forgot to connect the antenna to the card but left the card connected to the motherboard.

This would allow you to still connect to wireless devices but it would be very limited speed/distance from the WAP you could travel before it cut out.

Comment: It is true that both speed and distance were very limited. I couldn't find my neighbors Wi-Fis I can usually find. Moreover my connection to smartphone portable hotspot that was 20cm from my laptop was realy weak and unstable. Thanks Cory M !

Comment: I agree with @Cory M's answer.  The wireless adapter still transmits and receives even though the antennas are not connected.  Like Cory said, your range and performance will be affected.

Answer (score -1):

WiFi Adapter is a device which is used in laptops or desktop PC to install the service of WiFi in your computer.like if you got a computer and if it can not connect to the WiFi then  in that case you will need WiFi adapter so that your computer can connect to WiFi signals.in many computer it comes pre installed.